# IdentityServer3 connect/token endpoint always return 401: unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, token, identityserver3, endpoint

I am trying to setup IdentityServer3 for my project.

When I run IdentityServer3 on local development machine it works all fine, but when I host it on the shared server I get a 401 error. I am trying to access token using endpoint connect\token. Here is the configuration for identityserver3

```
IdentityServerOptions identityServerOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
{
    SiteName = "Ripple IdentityServer",
    SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
    AuthenticationOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions
    {
        EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
    },
    LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions
    {
        EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true,
        WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = true,
        EnableHttpLogging = true,
        EnableKatanaLogging = true
    },

    Factory = factory,
};
```

The strange thing is I am not getting any logs. I know the logs are working because when I access the connect/authorize endpoint, I can see log information. Here is my client registration

```
client = new Client
{
    ClientId = app.Id,
    ClientName = app.Name,
    Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,
    AllowedScopes = app.AllowedScopes.Split(';').ToList(),
    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> { "*" }
};
if (app.Secret != null && app.Secret != "")
{
    client.ClientSecrets = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Secret>();
    app.Secret = app.Secret.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");

    string[] secrets = app.Secret.Split(',');
    foreach (var s in secrets)
    {
        client.ClientSecrets.Add(new Secret(s.Sha256()));
    }
}
```

Here is the client code to get access token

```
var data = new StringContent(string.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}&Domain={2}&scope={3}",
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username),
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password),
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(domainId),
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(requiredScope)), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                string.Format("{0}:{1}", applicationId, appSecretKey))));

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("connect/token", data).Result;
```

Without logs, I am totally lost. Where should I look for more information to debug?

Comment: My client application is windows application which i am trying to execute from my desktop.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  I suspect that the username and credentials are not working.  Probably blocked because the credentials aren't encrypted.  I would check to see if you can get to the site using an Browser.  If so compare sniffer results in browser to your c# code.  Compare http headers.  Add missing header in c# that exists in Browser.

Comment: I used fiddler to capture traffic. Even with fiddler composer I am getting same result. I know credentials are correct because same credentials work for connect/authorize endpoint

Comment: So the status you are getting in fiddler is 401?  The connect/authorize returns a cookie.  Are you using the same cookie for additional requests?  Start by deleting all cookies.  The first request may or may not send a cookie depending if the cookie expired.  When you send the first request without a cookie a username and password are required.  The response will send back a cookie.  Then you must use the cookie in the next request.  The server probably doesn't allow more than one connection from the same IP which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Yes even with Fiddler I am getting 401.  I am

Comment: Yes even with fiddler I am getting 401.  I am using desktop application to make a call so I don’t think cookies are involved here. I am just guessing.

Comment: Are you sending the cookie returned in the response?  Do the webbrowser give error?

Comment: I am not sure what response and what cookie you are referring to. Error I am getting on first request to connect/token endpoint.

Comment: What are you using when you said " I know credentials are correct because same credentials work for connect/authorize endpoint"?  This is an http request that you should see in the sniffer.  You should be able to use same headers in your request and get a good response.  Capture the connect/authorize endpoint with the sniffer.  The compare with your app request.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. Shared hosting like godaddy did not support Basic authentication. So request to access token was getting rejected on server level. That was the reason why no log file was not are getting generated.

To work around this problem, I have to implement my own version on ISecretParser. In this implementation i parsed of my own authentication header

> e.g. Authentication MyAuth ClientID:ClientSecret

Then register this parser with IdentityServerServiceFactory and it worked like charm.

I hope this solution will help others who are trying to host IdentiyServer3 on shared servers.